# How to fix the following errors when I typed in "heroku logs --tail" on my terminal ?? what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, heroku, backend, nodemon

I just started learning how to code a month ago by watching many videos and tutorials. This is the first time I'm using stackoverflow to ask questions. I appreciate your time in reading this!
I'm in the process of deploying my app to Heroku but I'm not sure why it keeps showing up the following errors when I typed in "heroku open" in my terminal, it said I have "application error". I've already installed nodemon but it showed that "nodemon not found". I appreciate any help!
(mac version: macOS Mojave)

```
sh: 1: nodemon: not found
npm ERR! file sh
: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
: npm ERR! syscall spawn
: npm ERR! finalproject-api@0.1.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
: npm ERR!
: npm ERR! Failed at the finalproject-api@0.1.0 start script.
: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your `Procfile` to start your application with `node` instead of `nodemon`? `Nodemon` is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development, but not ideal to use on `Heroku` since `Heroku` supports the `node` buildpack and not `nodemon`.

Something like the following:

**Procfile:**

```
web: node server.js
```

Hopefully that fixes your issue!

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually don't have a Procfile in the folder but based on your suggestion, I updated my package.json and changed the code from 
"start": nodemon server.js to "start": node server.js. AND IT WORKED! Thank you sooo much again! I honestly don't know what Procfile is until your comment!

Comment: you can deploy nodejs application without Procfile as well but it is recommended to use it.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working please accept my answer :)